# Extend css with less

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, dotless

I'm trying to add my own less definition based on `glyphicon` in `bootstrap`. So I have this `.less` file:

```
/// <reference path="../Content/bootstrap.css" />

@import (reference) "../Content/bootstrap.css";

.status-ok-icon {
    .glyphicon;
    .glyphicon-ok;
    color: green;
}
```

But the compiler output returns:

```
.glyphicon is undefined on line 6 in file '/SiteCSS/client.less':
  [5]: .status-ok-icon {
  [6]:     .glyphicon;
       ----^
  [7]:     .glyphicon-ok;
```

Anybody could help me point out the mistake? I'm using less for the first time.

Comment: Well, that code works with the reference compiler so it's seems like your error above is a `dotless` specific issue.

Comment: On the other hand, `.glyphicon-ok` will fail in either version of Less anyway because there's no such ruleset/mixin in "bootstrap.css". In general see Mixins and Extend sections in the docs.

Comment: @seven-phases-max I see. I thought I can mixin from `css`, but appears I can only do it from `less`. Do you think if I switch to using raw `less` sources of `bootstrap` instead of compiled `css`, this will work? One thing that stopped me doing this is that I could not find an easy link to `less` variant of `bootstrap` which made me think it is not supposed to be used like that

Comment: You can use rulesets defined in CSS as mixins, but yet again, there no `.glyphicon-ok` ruleset in bootstrap.css (there's only `.glyphicon-ok:before` which does not match just `.glyphicon-ok` call). `Extend` would probably be what you're looking for but I'm not sure `dotless` is actually supports that, as it implements quite outdate dialect of Less).

Comment: Switching to Less version will help for your snippet above but I'd say implementing your own icon mixins/rulesets-for-extend for *any* font would be much more easy than trying to reuse some stuff not meant to be reused *that*
 way (after all the whole thing is just about 20 lines of code). (For instance see [this collection of links](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/cefc873a78fa12924462) for examples of what can go wrong if you try to use Bootstrap as a building-blocks library for semantic-like CSS (simply because Bootstrap is *not* such library)).